# ICurrentUser is null in abp multi layer MVC project

Tags: abp

I am using abp framework using MVC with multilayer and multitenancy enabled.
I also add MultiTenancy module and create a new tenant with admin account.

Below is the CLI Commands I used to create the solution

```
abp new FMSMultiTier -dbms MySQL --tiered -csf
abp add-module Volo.TenantManagement
```

After initial solution is created, I added one IMultiTenant Entity and create related Services as referred in the document

```
public class FairArea : AuditedAggregateRoot<Guid>, IMultiTenant
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public FairAreaType Type { get; set; }

        public Guid? TenantId { get; set; }
    }
```

In the services I injected ICurrentUser and ICurrentTenant, but none of them has the information for the current logged in user and its tenant information.

```
    public class FairAreaService: CrudAppService<
        FairArea,
        FairAreaDto,
        Guid,
        PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto,CreateUpdateFairAreaDto>,
        IFairAreaAppService 
    {
        private readonly IDataFilter _dataFilter;
        private readonly IRepository<FairArea, Guid> _fairAreaRepository;
        private readonly ICurrentTenant _currentTenant;
        private readonly ICurrentUser _currentUser;

    public FairAreaService(
        ICurrentTenant currentTenant,
        ICurrentUser currentUser,
        IDataFilter dataFilter,
        IRepository<FairArea, Guid> repository)
        : base(repository)
    {
        _dataFilter = dataFilter;
        _fairAreaRepository = repository;
        _currentTenant = currentTenant;
        _currentUser = currentUser;
    }
}
```

[image: ICurrentUser watch]

In the web UI , I can see that I am logged in with the correct user

[image: Logged in user is correct in the web ui]

Also my configuration for MultiTenancy is enabled in WebModule.cs and DomainModule.cs

WebModule.cs

```
public override void OnApplicationInitialization(ApplicationInitializationContext context)
{
var app = context.GetApplicationBuilder();
var env = context.GetEnvironment();

if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
app.UseAbpRequestLocalization();

app.UseCorrelationId();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();

if (MultiTenancyConsts.IsEnabled)
{
app.UseMultiTenancy();
}
```

DomainModule.cs

```
public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
    {
    
        Configure<AbpMultiTenancyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.IsEnabled = MultiTenancyConsts.IsEnabled;
        });

#if DEBUG
        context.Services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IEmailSender, NullEmailSender>());
#endif
}
```

Any ideas ?